# Finding a dynamic int inside a script that is in a html with bs4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I’m making an automatic account creator and I need help.
I need to get the highlited id from the script, the id is dynamic so it changes everytime you load the page. Its for captcha solving reasons, that is the challange id for the captcha and the captcha type is GeeTest. I saw some ways on here to get strings from a script but those were for static strings using slimit. I cant seem to find a way to access the scripts data w bs4.

Link to page : [https://secure.runescape.com/m=account-creation/create_account?theme=oldschool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmnU6.png)

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcoqo.png)